# SSRS WHERE Clause - Multiple parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

SSRS Conditional Date picker for a report

I have a report where I want to show products in inventory or products already sold or both. If they are in inventory, then no date range is required but if the user wants to include history, then i want to give the user the option to select the date range of the date the parts arrived in the warehouse. I've tried the following:
(Option 1 does not allow the nulled dates parameter to provide results):

```
WHERE (DashOrd.TypeSeq IN (@BERRYTYPE)) 
    AND (viewProductDashboard1n2combPt3.Location IN (@Locations)) 
    AND (LEFT(viewProductDashboard1n2combPt3.LotNumber, 3) IN (@Vendor)) 
    AND (viewProductDashboard1n2combPt3.Inv_Hist >= @INV_HIST) 
    AND (viewProductDashboard1n2combPt3.QC_Arr_Dt >= @Sdate) 
    AND (viewProductDashboard1n2combPt3.QC_Arr_Dt <= @Edate)
```

(Option is what SSRS changes my syntax to and seems to ignore the dates selected):

```
WHERE ((DashOrd.TypeSeq IN (@BERRYTYPE)) 
        AND (viewProductDashboard1n2combPt3.Location IN (@Locations)) 
        AND (LEFT(viewProductDashboard1n2combPt3.LotNumber, 3) IN (@Vendor)) 
        AND (viewProductDashboard1n2combPt3.Inv_Hist IN (@INV_HIST))
      ) 
    OR 
      (
        (DashOrd.TypeSeq IN (@BERRYTYPE)) 
        AND (viewProductDashboard1n2combPt3.Location IN (@Locations)) 
        AND (LEFT(viewProductDashboard1n2combPt3.LotNumber, 3) IN (@Vendor)) 
        AND (viewProductDashboard1n2combPt3.QC_Arr_Dt >= @Sdate) 
        AND (viewProductDashboard1n2combPt3.QC_Arr_Dt <= @Edate)
      )
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I've fixed a typo in the code ( missing `(` ) and arranged it so it's easier to visualise the logic (once the edit is approved). You need to edit your question to explain the code, explain what the tables/views are, we have no idea. Also when you said *SSRS changed my syntax*, are  you using the query designer? If so, try just editing the dataset query directly by dbl-clicking the dataset name, the designer is not very flexible.